# Do I need to delete duplicate SQS messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

In a use case that precludes the use of SQS FIFO queues, duplicate messages are a possibility.

If a consumer receives a duplicate message that it has already deleted, does it need to delete the duplicate?

I'm *guessing* that the answer is no, since duplicates are a function of the distributed implementation of SQS and assume that the delete action is just in the process of propagating through the AWS network, but is there any explicit documentation confirming this?

To clarify: **FIFO queues are not involved here**

Comment: Even if you somehow discover that it is not necessary to delete the duplicate message, deleting the message would be harmless.  You should delete it anyway.  That is certainly what you're *intended* to do, and otherwise you're complicating the message processing protocol for no good reason.

Answer (score -1):

If a consumer receive such kind of message which is duplicate of a deleted message,it will not be deleted. Because it already get out from the queue.

For the fifo queue you have to provide `MessageDeduplicationId` in the send message parameter. And this id have to be unique.

So when a message with `MessageDeduplicationId` is already preserved (e.g. your consumer can return the message for any kind of error occured, one probability for visibility timeout) in your whole queue, the duplicate copy will be automatically deleted.

For sending message you can read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sqs-examples-send-receive-messages.html)

For deduplication,  [learn more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html)

Comment: Again - FIFO queues are not relevant here; please reread the question